# Command Line to "batch" unrar many Archives into Subfolders accordingly

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch, 7-zip

in Windows 10, i have an folder F:\archive with about 300 different

"File 1.rar"
"Otherfilename 307.rar"

Knowing Linux better then Windows I spend some time to compile the following command and it worked well.

```
files.for /f "delims=" %a in ('dir *.rar /b /a-d') do (f:& cd \archives &@echo %~na &@mkdir  "%~na" & cd "\archives\%~na" &"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e "f:\archives\%~na.rar")&cd  cd \archives
```

First I tested it and it worked well. I wonder if this is working with other Windows Version (XP, 7, 8) as well and if not how to compile the command accordingly. 
Is it possible to replace the Path and Drive with Variables too? And still have a single line DOS command?

Comment: You should be able to use your script in all Versions you listed. I do not see any reason why any of the commands would not be supported if you had the software installed.

Comment: If you just want the job done, you could use the 7zip context menu. Mark all files, right click, and select `Extract to "*\"`. This will extract 123.rar to a folder called 123 .. etc.

Comment: What is `files.for`? At the beginning of your `for` command? That doesn't look right.

Comment: " Is it possible to replace the Path and Drive with Variables too? And still have a single line DOS command?" No. You need a batch file with parameters for this.